# how are the address of the pointers addressed?

Tags: c, pointers

I came across a quiz using C language relating to pointers, but I don't know if I got the answers right or wrong.
The following code is given and finding out the result.
By the way, the address for variable `a, p, q, r` is seen as `500, 600, 700, 800`.

```
int main(void)
{
   int  a = 10, *p = &a, **q = &p, ***r = &q;
   printf("%u %u %u %u %u", &a, p, q, r, *r);
  
   return 0;
}
```

What I thought was p points to a's address, q points to p's address, and r points to q's address. Therefore,  `&a` equals to `p`, and `q` equals to `*r`.

Therefore, I assumed the results would be `500 500 600 700 600`.

Would this be the correct answer?

Comment: You should not use `%u` to print pointers. Instead, use `%p`. Turn on your compiler warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if p holds the address of a,then p=500,again q holds the address of p,so  q=600,r holds address of q,so r=700,and *r=600..so final ans is 500,500,600,700,600.that means your assumption is absolutely right.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. One more thing, if I were to ```printf("%u %u %u %u %u", &a+1, p+1, q+1, r+1, *r+1);``` then would I have to add ```4``` to each address since an address takes 4Bytes of memories? The results would be ```504 504 604 704 604```?

Comment: @Learner_15 That could happen, but it would invoke undefined behavior so the result is not certain

Comment: @klutt hmm.. so I guess just simply looking at it at a beginner's view where I am just studying pointers, it should be the right answer the quiz is looking for.

Comment: Pointer arithmetics takes the size of objects into account, so it depends on the size of `int` on your current machine. Why don't you just try `printf("%p %p", &a, &a+1)` and see for yourself?

Comment: your ans is right..it would be 504,504,604,704,604.